# How to cat dynamic filename with date format

Tags: date, cat

I can use the command to devices id from /var/log/20140522.device.log.

Here is my command.

```
for i in `cat /var/log/20140522.device.log`; do echo ---$i; done
```

Now I want to make it by daily cron job, but it is not working.

```
for i in `cat /var/log/`/bin/date +%Y%m%d`.device.log`; do echo ---$i; done
```

Is it possible to put `cat` and `date` in one line?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; you can use `cat` and `date` on the same line using [command substution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

```
for file in $(cat /var/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d').device.log); do echo ----$file; done
```

Using the `$(…)` notation makes that nested operation much simpler than the back-tick notation:

```
for file in `cat /var/log/\`date +'%Y%m%d'\`.device.log`; do echo ----$file; done
```

You don't have to think as hard about where backslash escapes are needed.

Also, in Bash, you can avoid the use of `cat` with:

```
for file in $(</var/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d').device.log); do echo ----$file; done
```

Answer (score 2):

A `$` character need to be added as follows:

```
for i in `cat "/var/log/$(date +"%Y%m%d").device.log"`
```